# Having Issues attaching large file using php mail

Tags: php, attachment

my issue today is that I managed to send an image file with less than 1MB size using php mail function but when i tried to attach a file higher than 1MB it attaches to the mail but the file is empty or 0KB. I also managed to configure php.ini's post_max_size and upload_max_filesize and make it higher but there's still no change. Is there a way to fix this.

I'm using my localhost and php mail function is the only tool needed. No other libraries. Thank you

Comment: can you please share your code...

Comment: Have a look at the [fifth comment] (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on attaching large files.  You want to edit postfix/main.conf (message_size_limit) and php.ini (memory_limit).  But as the post suggest, its not recommended.  Best practice would be to use a library (I prefer PEAR Mail).